# How to extract views integration setting from the command line?

Tags: drupal-views, developer

Is there a way to output from the command line the views integration settings as listed in Administer > System Settings > CMS Database Integration? I need this as part of our upgrade script to automatically update settings.php (rewriting a php include file) every time a system upgrade is released.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you can code it (and because you are a scripter I suppose you are a coder). In CiviCRM, the views settings are generated in the with file https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/UF.php

I used this as inspiration to create the following script

```
<?php
$config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton();
$dsnArray = DB::parseDSN($config->dsn);
$tableNames = CRM_Core_DAO::getTableNames();
$tablePrefixes = '$databases[\'default\'][\'default\'][\'prefix\']= array(';
$tablePrefixes .= "\n  'default' => '$drupal_prefix',"; // add default prefix: the drupal database prefix
$prefix = "";
if ($config->dsn != $config->userFrameworkDSN) {
  $prefix = "`{$dsnArray['database']}`.";
}
foreach ($tableNames as $tableName) {
  $tablePrefixes .= "\n  '" . str_pad($tableName . "'", 41) . " => '{$prefix}',";
}
$tablePrefixes .= "\n);";

echo $tablePrefixes;
```

Run this script with the CiviCRM `cv` utility (see https://github.com/civicrm/cv) as follows.

```
cv scr <scriptname.php>
```

I tested this on CiviCRM 4.7.27

Comment: Cool! I will try this and let you know!